# Does computer use NFA or DFA?

Tags: automata

I am now learning about automation and I am wondering if personal computers use NFAs or DFAs.

I believe it uses a DFA since when we are clicking on something it is in a way determined what will happen. Any thoughts? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use something else, called a [RAM computational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), which is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (so it's equivalent to Turing machines).

Comment: @nir_shahar Thank you, still have not learned about turing machines. Thought the computer used a dfa or an nfa

Comment: @ili Notice that DFA's terminate after exactly $n$ steps (where $n$ is the number of characters in the input), but computers can run forever!